# On the discrete-time Fourier transform of unit step sequence.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

According to [1, page 11], the unit step sequence is given by
$$ u[n] =
\begin{cases}
1, & n \geq 0, \\
0, & n < 0.
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$
The discrete-time Fourier transform of $u[n]$ is [1, Table 2.3]
$$
U(e^{j \omega}) = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j \omega}} + \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \pi \delta(\omega + 2 \pi k). \tag{2}
$$
One of my students, Mr. Chang, wants to derive (2). The following is his derivation:
$$
U(e^{j \omega})
= \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty u[n] e^{-j \omega n}
= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty e^{-j \omega n}
= \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j \omega}}. \tag{3}
$$
$$
u[n] = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \delta[n - k]
\leftrightarrow U(e^{j \omega}) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty e^{-j \omega k}
= \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j \omega}}. \tag{4}
$$

The question is: Why do (3) and (4) not have the term
$$
\sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \pi \delta(\omega + 2 \pi k)? \tag{5}
$$

Thank you very much in advance.

## Reference:

[1] A. V. Oppenheim and R. W. Schafer, *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, 2nd ed., Prentice Hall, Inc., 1999.

Comment: The formula $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega n} = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-i\omega}}$$ is false. In general, the formula $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$$ holds only if $|z| < 1$. In particular, if $z = e^{-i \omega}$, then $|z| = 1$, so the formula does not hold.

Comment: Moreover, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega n}$ does not converge at all, because the terms do not converge to $0$. (The absolute value of each term is $1$.) So the claimed identity holds only in the sense of distributions.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you for your comments, Bungo. :-)